# parsing array elements in iPhone

Tags: iphone, arrays, parsing, coordinates

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *pthpath = [bundle pathForResource:@"path" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pthpath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    array=[[NSArray alloc ]init];
    array = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];
=====================================================================
```

here content is:

> 87,348~51,347~135,132~182,133~268,346~236,347~159,168~87,347@118,298~115,297~200,298~189,266~128,265~117,299@222,352~268,353~264,340~219,342~225,355@186,262~199,299~212,297~195,257~188,260

and array is:

> "87,348",
>       "51,347",
>       "135,132",
>       "182,133",
>       "268,346",
>       "236,347",
>       "159,168",
>       "87,347@118,298",
>       "115,297",
>       "200,298",
>       "189,266",
>       "128,265",
>       "117,299@222,352",
>       "268,353",
>       "264,340",
>       "219,342",
>       "225,355@186,262",
>       "199,299",
>       "212,297",
>       "195,257",
>       "188,260"

But I want to again create an array by parsing with @. Please help me out...........

Comment: question asked by invisible man/woman.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions, I've merged the second one into this.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (NSString *string in array) {
    NSArray *subArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
    for (NSString *substring in subArray)
       etc. etc.
```

(Next time try to have your question better formatted and articulated please.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using componentsSeparatedByString:, use componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: and create a character set with the separators you want.

Also, you are creating an array there (array = [[NSArray alloc] init]) and when you do array = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] you are leaking the just allocated array. In general, seems like you should read more about how objects and references work.

Comment: inorder to recover from leakingof array I use retain also, and until this its perfectly working.please give me code to split the got array again with ~

Comment: I gave you all the code you need in my first sentence. If you can't use what I gave you, then you shouldn't be doing this.        And even if you retain, you are leaking, because you are pointing "array" to a memory location, initializing that memory location, and then pointing it to somewhere else, so that first memory location is still allocated and nobody is using it or releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think from following code you may get some idea, if I understood your question correctly,

```
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    NSArray *tempArray1 = nil;
    NSArray *tempArray2 = nil;
    NSString *content = @"87,348~51,347~135,132~182,133~268,346~236,347~159,168~87,347@118,298~115,297~200,298~189,266~128,265~117,299@222,352~268,353~264,340~219,342~225,355@186,262~199,299~212,297~195,257~188,260";
    tempArray1 = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
    for(NSString *string in tempArray1)
    {
        tempArray2 = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"~"];
        [resultArray addObjectsFromArray:tempArray2];
    }

    NSLog(@"ResultArray :%@", resultArray);
```