# parsing array elements in iPhone

Tags: iphone, arrays

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *pthpath = [bundle pathForResource:@"path" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pthpath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    array=[[NSArray alloc ]init];
    array = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
=====================================================================
```

here content is
     87,348~51,347~135,132~182,133~268,346~236,347~159,168~87,347@118,298~115,297~200,298~189,266~128,265~117,299@222,352~268,353~264,340~219,342~225,355@186,262~199,299~212,297~195,257~188,260

and array is
 ARRAY (
    "87,348~51,347~135,132~182,133~268,346~236,347~159,168~87,347",
    "118,298~115,297~200,298~189,266~128,265~117,299",
    "222,352~268,353~264,340~219,342~225,355",
    "186,262~199,299~212,297~195,257~188,260"
But I want to again create an array by parsing with ~ .Please help me outt...........

Comment: Please don't double post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340225/parsing-array-elements-in-iphone